# When does AppLifecycleState toggle - flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I have this button that navigates to a new view:

```
RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('Advertise device', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          onPressed: () async {
            Nearby().askExternalStoragePermission();
            var navigationResult = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EndpointList(endpointList)));
            endpointList = navigationResult;
            Nearby().stopAdvertising();
            print("stopped advertising");
          }
        ),
```

The class implementing the view is declared with `with WidgetsBindingObserver` so that I can observe the view:

```
 @override
  void initState(){
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

When navigating to the view I want to call `_advertiseDevice();`. For some reason (that suits me), the `AppLifecycleState.resumed` gets toggled, so instead of calling `_advertiseDevice();` in the `initState()` it gets called here:

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if(state == AppLifecycleState.detached || state == AppLifecycleState.inactive || state == AppLifecycleState.paused){
      print("stopped advertising");
      Nearby().stopAdvertising();
    }else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
      print("advertising because state resumed");
      _advertiseDevice();
    }
  }
```

This is nice. View opens, and the `_advertiseDevice();` does his thing.

Now, I did the same with another view. Also called via a button:

```
RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('Discover devices', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          onPressed: () async {
            await Nearby().askLocationPermission();
            var navigationResult =  await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AdvertiserList(advertisingList)));
            advertisingList = navigationResult;
            Nearby().stopDiscovery();
            print("stopped discovering");
          },
        ),
```

and also declared with `with WidgetsBindingObserver` to observe the view:

```
  @override
  void initState(){
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

with a smilar didChangeAppLifecycleState:

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if(state == AppLifecycleState.detached || state == AppLifecycleState.inactive || state == AppLifecycleState.paused){
      print("stopped discovery");
      Nearby().stopDiscovery();
    }else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
      print("discovering because state resumed");
      _discoverDevices();
    }
  }
```

Here however, `AppLifecycleState.resumed` is not called when navigating to the view, like in the previous view. Yes, I can put the `_discoverDevices();` in the `initState()` and it would work just fine (the warning of "already discovering" that pops is irrelevant to me), but I'd like to know why.

Why two classes that implement the same WidgetsBindingObserver logic behave differently?

PS: I'm not adding the code for both classes because I'm still working on it and it's a mess and because (correct me if I'm mistaken), the actions performed by the view is irrelevant for this. This is related to the focus and unfocus of a view, and the actions taken accordingly.

EDIT: Adding the flow for both screens.

The app opens and displays a tab view. Within the first tab there are a couple buttons, one is the one that displays the first screen. Displaying it triggers `AppLifecycleState.resumed` and the `_advertiseDevice();` method is called. (Why? No idea, the app lifecycle didn't change).

The app opens and displays a tab view. Select the second tab. Within the second tab there are a couple buttons, one is the one that displays the second screen. Displaying it does not trigger anything, unlike the first screen. No idea why the difference in behaviour.

Comment: The 2nd View is pushed above the 1st one ? I mean, when pushing to 2nd View, 1st one was in Navigation Stack ?

Comment: No, they are used independently. I'm testing with two devices and one uses the first, another uses the second. I did test swapping devices, in case it was an OS problem, but swapping showed the same problem.

Comment: `Nearby` is a service ?

Comment: Yes. It's a google service designed to connect to nearby users. I'm using this plugin in my project: https://pub.dev/packages/nearby_connections I just use Nearby() to call methods like discover, advertise, connect, disconnect... I believe it does not affect my problem.

Comment: In the past I have faced similar problem. Digging into, I found that a clean approach would be to use a global AppLifecycleStateChangeListener. And depending to lifecycle, make the call to our services

Comment: That's a neat idea. In my case, it's not a problem, I'll just call my methods on the `initState`, but still, I'm curious as to why this happens. What is the source of the problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get any native popup on the first screen ? If so, that might be the cause. The lifecycle you're listening to are for App lifecycles not for "screens". So it doesn't matter if the screens are visible or not (due to push/pop) what it's important is the fact that the whole app is visible. If you go to second screen, and move the app to bg and you bring it back in foreground, you'll get the message for sure.

Comment: No, I get no popus on the first screen. I edited the post with the flow of both screens.